# how to set date interval for counting id in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with columns `parsed_date` (dtype: date) and `id` (dtype: bigint) as shown below:

```
+-------+-----------+
|     id|parsed_date|
+-------+-----------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|
|1471885| 2017-12-18|
|1472928| 2017-12-19|
|1476917| 2017-12-19|
|1477469| 2017-12-21|
|1478190| 2017-12-21|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|
|1481415| 2017-12-21|
|1472592| 2017-12-20|
|1474023| 2017-12-22|
|1474029| 2017-12-22|
+-------+-----------+
```

I have a function as shown below. The aim is to pass a date (day) and t (no. of days). In df1 the id are counted in the range (day-t, day) and in df2 the id are counted in range (day, day+t).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

def hypo_1(df, day, t):

    df1 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' - interval {t} days and '{day}'")
             .withColumn('count_before', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    df2 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' and '{day}' + interval {t} days")
             .withColumn('count_after', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    return [df1, df2]
```

With this code the function returns two dataframes:

example: hypo_1(df, '2017-12-20', 2)

df1

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
|parsed_date|     id|count_before|
+-----------+-------+------------+
| 2017-12-20|1471783|           1|
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

df2

```
+-----------+-------+-----------+
|parsed_date|     id|count_after| 
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 2017-12-20|1472592|          1|
| 2017-12-21|1477469|          3|
| 2017-12-22|1474029|          2|
+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

Issues:

1. The interval of date for df1 does not look right.
2. the id for the date (2017-12-20) I pass should not be calculated, which is happening in both df1 and df2 ->

   ```
    +-----------+-------+-----------+
    |parsed_date|     id|count_after| 
    +-----------+-------+-----------+
    | 2017-12-20|1472592|          1|
   ```

Expected output:

example: hypo_1(df, '2017-12-20', 2)

df1:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|           3|
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

df2:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|parsed_date| count_after|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1477469| 2017-12-21|           3|
|1474023| 2017-12-22|           2|
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your filter conditions a bit (add `- interval 1 day` or `+ interval 1 day`):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

def hypo_1(df, day, t):
    df1 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' - interval {t} days and '{day}' - interval 1 day")
             .withColumn('count_before', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    df2 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' + interval 1 day and '{day}' + interval {t} days")
             .withColumn('count_after', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    return [df1, df2]

df1, df2 = hypo_1(df, '2017-12-20', 2)
df1.show()
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1471885| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1472928| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1476917| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|           3|
+-------+-----------+------------+

df2.show()
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_after|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|1481415| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1478190| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1477469| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1474023| 2017-12-22|          2|
|1474029| 2017-12-22|          2|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

If you want to get your desired output, you can remove duplicates, e.g.

```
df1 = df1.dropDuplicates(['parsed_date', 'count_after'])
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it. it works just fine. I am wondering how will this code react if a date is missing within the range? let's say there is no record for 2017-12-22 ? Is it possible to have immediate days that are in the record? I mean if 2017-12-22 and the next date after 2017-12-21 is 2017-12-24 so is it possible to take that somehow?

Comment: It should be possible. You can assign a `dense_rank` ordered by parsed_date, and filter the rows with `dense_rank <= 2`. Feel free to open another question and provide some sample dataframe to test on :)

Comment: thank you @mck, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446431/count-id-for-date-range-in-pyspark) has been created.

Comment: also for df1 i changed the interval `f"parsed_date between '{day}' - interval {t+1} days and '{day}' - interval 1 day"` to `f"parsed_date between '{day}' - interval {t} days and '{day}' - interval 1 day"` as it was taking `t+1` days instead of `t`.

Comment: yes, that's right, I don't know why I put t+1 there... that's a mistake.