# count id for date range in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, count

I have a pyspark dataframe with columns parsed_date (dtype: date) and id (dtype: bigint) as shown below:

```
+-------+-----------+
|     id|parsed_date|
+-------+-----------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|
|1471885| 2017-12-18|
|1472928| 2017-12-19|
|1476917| 2017-12-19|
|1477469| 2017-12-21|
|1478190| 2017-12-21|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|
|1481415| 2017-12-21|
|1472592| 2017-12-20|
|1474023| 2017-12-22|
|1474029| 2017-12-22|
|1474067| 2017-12-24|
+-------+-----------+
```

I have a function as shown below. The aim is to pass a date (day) and t (no. of days). In df1 the id are counted in the range (day-t, day) and in df2 the id are counted in range (day, day+t).

```
def hypo_1(df, day, t):
    df1 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' - interval {t} days and '{day}' - interval 1 day")
             .withColumn('count_before', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    df2 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date between '{day}' + interval 1 day and '{day}' + interval {t} days")
             .withColumn('count_after', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    return [df1, df2]

df1, df2 = hypo_1(df, '2017-12-20', 2)
df1.show()
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1471885| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1472928| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1476917| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|           3|
+-------+-----------+------------+

df2.show()
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_after|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|1481415| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1478190| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1477469| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1474023| 2017-12-22|          2|
|1474029| 2017-12-22|          2|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am wondering how can this code be fixed if a date is missing within the range? let's say there is no record for `2017-12-22` ? Is it possible to have immediate days that are in the record? I mean if `2017-12-22` is not there and the next date after `2017-12-21` is `2017-12-24` so is it possible to take that somehow?

credits to [mck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165730/mck) for helping in creating the function `hypo_1(df, day, t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `2017-12-22` rows to illustrate. The idea is to get a `dense_rank` ordered by date (descending for before, ascending for after), and filter the rows with rank <= 2, i.e. the two closest dates.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

def hypo_1(df, day, t):
    df1 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date < '{day}'")
             .withColumn('rn', F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.desc('parsed_date'))))
             .filter('rn <= 2')
             .drop('rn')
             .withColumn('count_before', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    df2 = (df.filter(f"parsed_date > '{day}'")
             .withColumn('rn', F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('parsed_date')))
             .filter('rn <= 2')
             .drop('rn')
             .withColumn('count_after', F.count('id').over(Window.partitionBy('parsed_date')))
             .orderBy('parsed_date')
          )
    return [df1, df2]

df1, df2 = hypo_1(df, '2017-12-20', 2)
df1.show()
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1471783| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1471885| 2017-12-18|           2|
|1472928| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1476917| 2017-12-19|           3|
|1478570| 2017-12-19|           3|
+-------+-----------+------------+

df2.show()
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|     id|parsed_date|count_after|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|1477469| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1481415| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1478190| 2017-12-21|          3|
|1474067| 2017-12-24|          1|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: the code works absolutely fine. thanks a tone. since the dataset I have has billions of rows, so this is taking a lot of time. By any chance there is a way to optimise the speed?

Comment: I think one possible way is to use the filter in your previous question, but set it to something like 10 days, so that you don't need to calculate the dense_rank for every single row.

Comment: I would like to ask a follow up question. sorry for such a delay because earlier I was using the solution for a small dataset and now I want to use a heavy dataset. when I am trying df.show() my code gets stuck and I see this `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.` . Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try adding a filter as I said in the above comment?

Comment: I am not sure where to put a filter ? can you help please?

Comment: try changing the filter `parsed_date < '{day}'` to something like `parsed_date < '{day}' and parsed_date > '{day}' - interval 10 days`

Comment: `parsed_date > '{day}' - interval 10 days` what does this do?

Comment: and for `parsed_date > '{day}` should I be doing `parsed_date > '{day}' and parsed_date < '{day}' - interval 10 days` instead?

Comment: should be + for the second filter - think about the logic. It filters the dates which is within 10 days, which hopefully can reduce the number of rows

Comment: ya I get the logic now, ofcourse - for second filter does not make sense. thanks for pointing that out. it should be `parsed_date < '{day}' + interval 10 days and parsed_date > '{day}'`

Comment: Also, won't it be `filter('rn >= 2')` for second case?

Comment: no, the window ordering is opposite in the second case